How to add CSS to text located in submit.php file
A contact form forms part of a single-page website. It is situated at the bottom of the page. When the form is completed successfully by a user a 'success' message is generated and displayed immediately above the contact form. I wish to add CSS to the text of that message. Specifically, centering the text and changing the colour.
The form is controlled by contact.php and submit.php. The actual text is contained in an 'echo' statement in submit.php.
contact form code
<div class="container">
     <div id="responseMessage"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="form-inner-cnt" id="contact-page">
            <!--  -->
            <!-- <form action="" method="post" class="cnt-form"> -->
             <form id="contactForm" method="post" class="cnt-form">
                
                <!-- Status message -->
                                
                <!-- Form fields -->
                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value="" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" required=""></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="SEND">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

Part of submit.php
        // Send email
                // @mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $htmlContent, $headers);

                //   echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Thank you for your message. We will respond as soon as possible.']);


            if (mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $htmlContent, $headers)) {

                echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'THANK YOU FOR YOUR MESSAGE. WE WILL RESPOND AS SOON AS POSSIBLE.']);
            } else {
                echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Failed to send your message.']);
            }
} 
?>

Any assistance would be much appreciated

Your submit.php isn't directly giving the response you see on the page - it is returning JSON. So there must be some additional JavaScript involved, that sends the form field values to the server via AJAX/fetch, and then puts the response message from the received JSON, into the current document. But seeing that there is an existing HTML div element #responseMessage, that's presumably what the response will be inserted into? So format that element according to your wishes then, via your stylesheet ...?

Hi, thanks for the info. There is indeed an AJAX script. there are a number of other specific stylesheets and one separate 
Hi, thanks for the info. There is indeed an AJAX script. there are a number of other specific stylesheets and one separate 
You didn't include the JS code which processes the form submission, or state explicitly where the success message is shown, but I assume the response message that submit.php returns is placed into
<div id="responseMessage"></div>

?
If so you can add a simple CSS rule which targets that element by its id and changes its style, e.g.
#responseMessage {
  color: red;
}

You can add the CSS rule either in

a .css file linked to from the contact.php file (via a <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> type of link), or

a <style>...</style> tag inline within the page.


A 3rd option is to put the rule directly into the style attribute of the <div> but generally that's not as readable or maintainable, so most people would advise you to avoid doing that unless for some reason you have no other option.
N.B. Centring the <div> may be a little more complex than simply adding a style directly to the div itself - I leave that as a research exercise for the reader for now..the question was about how/where to add the CSS, which is explained here.

I tried the easiest option first but unless I made a mistake in the code, it didn't work - no colour change.


@tosalet thing is, that's not the easiest option :-). Cos you have to adapt it - you can't put a CSS selector into there (there's no need if you think about it, because it's being applied only to the element the style attribute belongs to), you just put the attribute(s) you want, e.g.: style="color: red;" . But that's a nasty way to do it because it makes your disaprate styles harder to find and review and debug later, and of course if you want to apply the same thing to several elements, it makes it impossible without lots of repetition. So that's why it's generally only a last resort

There is only one php file involved - submit.php The relevant code for the message is;       if (mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $htmlContent, $headers)) {
echo json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'THANK YOU FOR YOUR MESSAGE. WE WILL RESPOND AS SOON AS POSSIBLE.']);
} else {
echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Failed to send your message.']);
}
The contact form is in the index page (the only page) with html:   <div id="responseMessage"
Your style code has been tried both in this div and in the index page style statement

Clearly I have misunderstood or made a mistake in applying your instructions.

I am pleased to say that I did make a mistake. I entered your CSS style into the existing page style statement which as you know did not work. Today I placed it into a new 
ADyson OK, centering is completed. All that remains is to thank you very much for your assistance  - and perseverance!

No problem. Normally on stackoverflow the way to say thanks is to mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you solve your problem (and/or add an upvote). P.S. Not sure why it didn't work in an existing style tag, but ok, as long as you found a way.
